# Why would I check to see if a date is less than 0 or less than the year 1900 in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am reusing logic in my query from someone else's code.  In their where statement, which is lengthy and highly unreadable, there are several instances where date fields are being compared and checked to see if they are less than zero.

ie

```
YEAR(bp.dtGoalDate) <= 1900
    AND (po.GoalDate IS NULL OR  po.GoalDate < 0)
```

dtGoalDate and GoalDate are Date/Time columns in our database.  Is this something that I don't understand and is perfectly normal or is this poorly written and needs cleaned up?

Comment: That looks like they are just checking for bad or nonexistent dates. Run a query against the table and look for GoalDate < 0 and see if anything returns.

Comment: if you have legacy server feeding your system they may use two digits for year, so when they see 18 they think 1918 instead of 2018. Beside that is hard to guess.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I think you nailed it. When I see this kind of code I guess someone got a bad day with date format hell/localization/unsanity data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to see it on action. date 0 is equal to `1900-01-01`

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/BAHG37599)**

```
create table t1 (
    t datetime
)    

insert into t1 values ('2018-01-01');
insert into t1 values (0);
insert into t1 values ('1800-01-01');

SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE t <= 0
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: from @dfundako and your answer I ran some tests and indeed there were 4 erroneous dates out of millions of rows for 12/15/1899.  Someone made a mistake and assigned dates to the month prior to a null date (1/1/1900).  Makes sense now.